# c# linq join on entity model, chain gets long referencing values

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework and I have this linq expression which joins on 2 tables:

```
var defects = context.Defects.Join(context.DocumentStores, rtd => rtd.DefectID, ds => ds.DocumentID, 
        (rtd, ds) => new {rtd, ds}).Where(w => w.rtd.ReportID == "id");
```

Then I iterate over defects and I can reference each individual table like so:

```
foreach(var defect in defects)
{
    defect.rtd.SomeProperty;
    defect.ds.SomeOtherProperty;
}
```

Now the issue I am having is if I have more than one join the number of properties I have to chain down to increases and I end up repeating myself. Take this query:

```
var defects = context.Defects
    .Join(context.DocumentStores, rtd => rtd.DefectID, ds => ds.DocumentID, (rtd, ds) => new {rtd, ds})
    .Join(context.Reports, rtd => rtd.rtd.ReportID, r => r.ReportID, (rtd, r) => new { rtd, r })
    .Where(w => w.rtd.ReportID == "id");
```

Now in order to reference fields in the loop I have to go:

defect.rtd.rtd.SomeProperty;

Is this normal behaviour or is there a way to keep it as one grouping?

Comment: There's maybe a better way, but anyway, I think that query syntax is much (much) clearer when working with joins (even if I'm usually an adept of fluent syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested before the query syntax may be clearer for multiple join.

```
var defects =
    from d in context.Defects
    where d.ReportID == "id"
    join ds in context.DocumentStores on d.DefectId equals ds.DocumentID
    join r in context.Reports on d.ReportId equals r.ReportId
    select new {
        RepId= r.ReportId, 
        DocId = ds.DocumentID
        // other assignments
    };
```

anyway you can use the following synthax:

```
    var defects = context.Defects
        .Join(context.DocumentStores, rtd => rtd.DefectID, ds => ds.DocumentID, (rtd, ds) => new {rtd, ds})
        .Join(context.Reports, rtd => rtd.rtd.ReportID, r => r.ReportID, (rtd, r) => new { rtd, r })
        .Where(w => w.rtd.ReportID == "id")
        .Select(s=> new {
        DefectID=s.rtd.rtd.DefectID
        //....
       });
```